# ls does not list files as expected

Tags: bash

I'm facing the following problem:

Output1

```
sh-3.2$ ls -R
.:
#dir1  #dir2

./#dir1:
f1  f2  f3

./#dir2:
f1  f2  f3
```

Output2

```
sh-3.2$ ls #dir1
#dir1  #dir2
```

As seen in Output1 the directory `#dir1` has file `f1 f2 and f3` but when
I do a ls on the directory I get a different output as seen in Output2
Output2 seems to suggest that `#dir1` has directories like `#dir1 #dir2`.

What is going on here? Is this some cyclic link?

Comment: Nice to see you got a good answer, but I've voting to move this to Super User which I believe is a more appropriate site...

Answer (score 8):

`#` is a shell meta char which marks the ***beginning of a comment***. Hence

```
ls #dir1
```

is effectively same as

```
ls
```

which lists everything in the cwd.

try escaping the `#`

```
ls \#dir1
```

or or quoting the entire dir name:

```
ls '#dir1'
```

or

```
ls ./#dir1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Me and my project mates we having some hard time with this

Answer (score 3):

In the command `ls #dir1`, the shell interprets the hash character as the beginning of a comment -- so you get a listing of the current working directory.